# Multiple currency symbol positions within a single locale

Tags: multistore, localisation

I've seen several articles that talk about changing the currency symbol position in the locale xml file. However, this seems to change the position for every type of currency, which is not ideal for a store that supports multiple currencies. It seems like currency positioning would be split out into its own configuration, not tied to locale.

How do I change the currency symbol position for specific currency types?

Comment: Was your question answered? Then please mark a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use free extension [ET Currency Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html). This extension extends class Mage_Directory_Model_Currency (you can rewrite function format() from this class without this extension).

Answer (score 0):

Well I've written a code long time before [here](http://subesh.com.np/2010/08/displaying-currency-code-after-the-price-value-in-magento/), you can use the same method, but before setting `'position' => Zend_Currency::RIGHT` you could use your own configurations from XML or DB values to set appropriate position.

Comment: Please add the linked code/method as the link is no longer functioning.